# Jetty + SpringMVC: Error when set configureDefaultServletHandling because cannot find the default servlet name

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, embedded-jetty

I created an simple application without web.xml and spring-servlet.xml config file. I just config in Java code.
This is the project structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw9iu.png)

This is my main class:

```
public class TripMapServer {

private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";
private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "com.biendltb.config";
private static final String DEFAULT_PROFILE = "dev";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TripMapServer().startJetty(getPortFromArgs(args));
}

private static int getPortFromArgs(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        }
    }
    return DEFAULT_PORT;
}

private void startJetty(int port) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(port);
    server.setHandler(getServletContextHandler(getContext()));
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

private static ServletContextHandler getServletContextHandler(WebApplicationContext context) throws IOException {
    ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
    contextHandler.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
    contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DispatcherServlet(context)), MAPPING_URL);
    contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    contextHandler.setResourceBase(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
    return contextHandler;
}

private static WebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
    context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles(DEFAULT_PROFILE);
    return context;
 }
}
```

I created another class named WebConfig.java to set the config for spring-servlet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.biendltb.controller"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{ 

private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

@Autowired
public Environment env;

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(stringConverter());
}

private StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", UTF8)));
    return stringConverter;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/src/main/resources/").setCachePeriod(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/src/main/resources/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
 }
}
```

Error happened when I add the **configureDefaultServletHandling** function.

```
[org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate the default servlet for serving static content. Please set the 'defaultServletName' property explicitly.
```

It cannot find the default name of servlet. Normally, the default name of servlet will be "default".

I think maybe I should set the servlet name to solve this problem.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Sorry about the code format not display correctly. Appreciated you support. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found how to set the name for Spring servlet by java code:

```
contextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder("default", new DispatcherServlet(context)), MAPPING_URL);
```

But I met another issue, that is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException
```

I try to google, many people faced with **NoClassDefFoundError** but no one met the issue **org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException**.

I checked again to make sure all dependency were added.

Maybe I should post another question for that issue :(

Comment: Such a NoClassDefFoundError typically happens as a consequence of a StackOverFlow, typically between Spring MVC and the container default servlet